# Initializing empty polymorphic Singleton type without magic statics

Tags: multithreading, c++11, singleton

Suppose you had a polymorphic Singleton type (in our case a custom [`std::error_category`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_category) type). The type is stateless, so no data members, but it does have a couple of virtual functions. The problem arises when instantiating this type in a multithreaded environment.

The easiest way to achieve this would be to use C++11's [magic statics](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm):

```
my_type const& instantiate() {
    static const my_type instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Unfortunately, one of our compilers (VC11) does not support this feature.

- Should I expect that this will explode in a multithreaded environment? I'm quite certain that as far as the standard goes, all bets are off. But given that the type does not contain any data members and only virtual functions, what kind of errors should I expect from a mainstream implementation like VC11? For example, neither Boost.System nor VC seem to take any precautions against this in their implementation of `error_category`. Are they just being careless or is it unreasonably paranoid to worry about races here?
- What would be the best way to get rid of the data race in a standard-compliant way? Since the type in this case is an `error_category` I want to avoid doing a heap allocation if possible. Keep in mind that the Singleton semantics are vital in this case, since equality of error categories is determined by pointer-comparison. This means that for example thread-local storage is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possibly simpler version of Casey's answer, which uses an atomic spinlock to guard a *normal static declaration*.

```
my_type const& instantiate()
{
  static std::atomic_int flag;
  while (flag != 2)
  {
    int expected = 0;
    if (flag.compare_exchange_weak(expected, 1))
      break;
  }
  try
  {
    static my_type instance = whatever; // <--- normal static decl and init

    flag = 2;
    return instance;
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    flag = 0;
    throw;
  }
}
```

This code is also easier to turn into three macro's for reuse, which are easily `#defined` to nothing on platforms which support magic statics.

```
my_type const& instantiate()
{
  MY_MAGIC_STATIC_PRE;

  static my_type instance = whatever; // <--- normal static decl and init

  MY_MAGIC_STATIC_POST;

  return instance;

  MY_MAGIC_STATIC_SCOPE_END;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Attempt #2b: Implement your own equivalent of [`std::once_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag), with an `atomic<int>` ([Live at Rextester](http://rextester.com/XSJJM57819)):

```
my_type const& instantiate() {
    static std::aligned_storage<sizeof(my_type), __alignof(my_type)>::type storage;
    static std::atomic_int flag;

    while (flag < 2) {
        // all threads spin until the object is properly initialized
        int expected = 0;
        if (flag.compare_exchange_weak(expected, 1)) {
            // only one thread succeeds at the compare_exchange.
            try {
                ::new (&storage) my_type;
            } catch(...) {
                // Initialization failed. Let another thread try.
                flag = 0;
                throw;
            }
            // Success!
            if (!std::is_trivially_destructible<my_type>::value) {
                std::atexit([] {
                    reinterpret_cast<my_type&>(storage).~my_type();
                }); 
            }
            flag = 2;
        }
    }

    return reinterpret_cast<my_type&>(storage);
}
```

This only relies on the compiler to correctly zero-initialize all static storage duration objects, and also uses the nonstandard extension `__alignof(<type>)` to properly align `storage` since Microsoft's compiler team can't be bothered add the keyword without the two underscores.

---

Attempt#1: Use [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) in conjunction with a [`std::once_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag) ([Live demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0a4964464bd26fa)):

```
my_type const& instantiate() {
    struct empty {};
    union storage_t {
        empty e;
        my_type instance;
        constexpr storage_t() : e{} {}
        ~storage_t() {}
    };

    static std::once_flag flag;
    static storage_t storage;

    std::call_once(flag, []{
        ::new (&storage.instance) my_type;
        std::atexit([]{
            storage.instance.~my_type();
        }); 
    });

    return storage.instance;
}
```

The default constructor for `std::once_flag` is `constexpr`, so it's guaranteed to be constructed during constant initialization. I am under the impression [citation needed] that VC correctly performs constant initialization. EDIT: Unfortunately, MSVC up through VS12 still doesn't support `constexpr`, so this technique has some undefined behavior. I'll try again.

Comment: A bit more code than I'd like, but it achieves the goal of threadsafety without exporting any objects outside the function definition or having any involvement in the static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: You should use atomic_int rather than atomic<int> because there is a default constructor in atomic<int> which sets the flag to 0 at function-run-time. If the happens while a previous thread has just set it to 1 , you will get two threads entering the critical section.  atomic_int is still initialised to 0, but this happens at program-startup-time when a race condition is impossible.

Comment: @Ian Yes, thank you, I forgot about MSVC failing to correctly implement trivial default construction for `atomic<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

The standard is silent on the question of how statics are constructed when the function is called on multiple threads.

gcc uses locks to make function level statics threadsafe (can be disabled by a flag). Most (all?) versions of Visual C++ do NOT have threadsafe function level statics.

It is recommended to use a lock around the variable declaration to guarantee thread-safety.

Comment: C++11 [stmt.dcl]/4 is not silent: "...such a variable is
initialized the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon
the completion of its initialization. If the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization
is not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control enters the declaration. If control enters
the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for
completion of the initialization."